# difference between session expired and invalidated

Tags: java, session, session-state, session-timeout, session-cookies

What is the difference between expired session and invalidate session?

And also, how to make session expired in java?

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have asked 5 questions and accepted 0 answers. Mark some answers as accepted, if they properly answer your questions

Comment: бе и аз мога да пиша на български, ама.. ;) in other words - use English.

Answer (score 7):

- a session expires, when no request has been created by the user for a given period of time
- a session is invalidated when the server invalidates it (in Java - `session.invalidate()`